# Google Docs Spreadsheet to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've seen numerous articles on this but they seem outdated, for instance none of the Google Docs Spreadsheet urls has key parameter. I read this as well:
[JSON data from google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230760/json-data-from-google-spreadsheet)

Then I read this to access data
    https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample

My spreadsheet exists at: 
    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SKI5773_68HiSve1fsz7fr4gotjFWHB7KBuVsOlLz6I/edit#gid=0

I've tried using this code, I think I have a problem with the key or syntax, please guide to fix.

```
<script src="http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/feed/1SKI5773_68HiSve1fsz7fr4gotjFWHB7KBuVsOlLz6I/worksheet/public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=importGSS"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function importGSS(json) {
        console.log('finished');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `src` attribute in your `script` tag is an invalid link (and you can see this for yourself by [viewing your link directly in a browser](http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/feed/1SKI5773_68HiSve1fsz7fr4gotjFWHB7KBuVsOlLz6I/worksheet/public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=importGSS)).

The `feed/key/worksheet` section of the URL has the right `key` but the wrong `feed` and `worksheet`.

In the URL, replace "`feed`" with either "`cells`" (separate value for each cell) or "`list`" (separate value for each row).

At the same time, replace "`worksheet`" with "`od6`" (indicating the leftmost, or default, sheet - see [this blog post](http://damolab.blogspot.com/2011/03/od6-and-finding-other-worksheet-ids.html) for accessing other sheets).

If you [view this new URL directly in a browser](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1SKI5773_68HiSve1fsz7fr4gotjFWHB7KBuVsOlLz6I/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=importGSS), you can see that it returns a meaningful value.

Your final script tag might look like this:

```
<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1SKI5773_68HiSve1fsz7fr4gotjFWHB7KBuVsOlLz6I/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=importGSS"></script>
```

For more info, you can see an example on the [Google Developers site](https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample)

Comment: thanks, It's working, can you please explain the usage of cells or list with an example, and you referred 0d6 as the leftmost default sheet, how to access other sheets in case, 0d6 seems like some octal code for the given sheet.

Comment: thanks for the edit, but please explain the difference between "cells" and "list" and how did we know that 0d6 refers to the first sheet, how do I find codes for the rest of the sheets if any

Comment: @user2727195 - here's a [blog post for finding other worksheet ids](http://damolab.blogspot.com/2011/03/od6-and-finding-other-worksheet-ids.html)

Comment: read the blog, and I think I'd be able to get hold of worksheet id's, lastly what's the difference between "cells" or "list" parameter, how do I use them

Comment: @user2727195 - glad to hear it's working...perhaps you wouldn't mind clicking the checkbox to indicate you've accepted the answer...

Comment: sure, I did, can you please enlighten me on the difference between "cells" and "list"

Comment: the `list` call returns 1 entry for each row in your spreadsheet, while the `cells` call returns 1 entry for each cell

Comment: I noticed in google docs that some vars are returned as gd$var-name but in my case I'm returned an object called content, and inside $t is a comma separated list of var-name: value, Instead of splitting based on comma how google docs itself can create variables as per the headers in the column https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArCVqqr4VE_pdGNSOEFIU3hBUlJJbnNJaXkxeGZpamc&usp=drive_web#gid=2

Comment: Late to the party, but do you know why when using `list`the first column is not fetched? I ended up using an empty column as my first column.

Answer (score 1):

APISpark PaaS has a feature to create and deploy a custom JSON API based on a GSpreadsheet. That might help and give you more control on the web API (CORS support, authentication, custom domain and so on).

See the tutorial here: https://apispark.com/docs/tutorials/google-spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

You may consider use an alternative to this request of your sheet data, because this method is deprecated.
Anyway, you can still using another feed format, you can see this alternatives in:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/your-spreadsheet-id/private/full

In that result you can see any export formats are availables. Can help you an CSV or alt JSON visualization format?

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution here is to use this https://gist.github.com/ronaldsmartin/47f5239ab1834c47088e to wrap around your existing spreadsheet.

Add the `id` and `sheet` html param to the URL below.

> https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzGvKKUIaqsMuCj7-A2YRhR-f7GZjl4kSxSN1YyLkS01_CfiyE/exec

Eg: your `id` is your sheet id which is

`1SKI5773_68HiSve1fsz7fr4gotjFWHB7KBuVsOlLz6I`

and your sheet which is

`Sheet1`

In your case you can actually see your data (it's actually working) here as json at

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzGvKKUIaqsMuCj7-A2YRhR-f7GZjl4kSxSN1YyLkS01_CfiyE/exec?id=1SKI5773_68HiSve1fsz7fr4gotjFWHB7KBuVsOlLz6I&sheet=Sheet1

To be safe, you should deploy the code `sheetAsJson.gs` in the github gist above as your own in your Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of possible answers above. For those that come anew, if you're looking for a more controlled JSON generator, check out this gist:

[JSONPuller](https://gist.github.com/jalcantarab/0eb43b13c97e4f784bd0be327f6ced52)

It takes in a Spreadsheet and returns an array of objects, with the lined that you decide as the headers (defaults to whichever line is frozen)

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

[This Chrome extension](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/sheets-to-json/enmkalgdnmcaljdfkojckdbhkjmffmoa) might work for you. It adds a JSON button in the toolbar for all google sheets

P.S. I'm the dev

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35437259)

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way for me was to export spreadsheet to CSV

`File -> Download -> Comma-separated values`

Then just convert CSV to JSON with free online servic