# google spreadsheet json format (How to open)

Tags: json, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a publicly shared excel sheet which i want to retrieve in JSON format. I tried following instruction here but it didn't work. 
Can somebody please guide me on this.
My sheet:    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PDKO3PK-ZvRmZddpqMlEdjsOhXAJngw7ajU3opY-J1M/pubhtml

any tutorial on the latest way of doing something like :
https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641492/google-docs-spreadsheet-to-json

Comment: yes..I just did with URL as

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1PDKO3PK-ZvRmZddpqMlEdjsOhXAJngw7ajU3opY-J1M/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=importGSS

but it doesn't work..:(

Comment: This works for me (Insert your spreadsheet ID): https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/<SpreadsheetID>/default/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=importGSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it with my own spreadsheet, and this seems to work:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/<SpreadsheetKey>/default/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=importGSS
```

Just insert your spreadsheet ID from your spreadsheet:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<SpreadsheetKey>/edit#gid=0
```

**EDIT:** 
Tried it with [yours](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1PDKO3PK-ZvRmZddpqMlEdjsOhXAJngw7ajU3opY-J1M/default/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=importGSS) as well - works!

Comment: thank you so much..I hope it will be easy to consume the json i see on the webpage to display nicely on web page.