# Getting JSON data from Google Spreadsheets - Uncaught TypeError

Tags: jquery, json

I have tried a couple of methods, including the one from this post : [JSON data from google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230760/json-data-from-google-spreadsheet)

However, none of it works. I created a simple test table in google docs, and published it. You can see the published version of the spreadsheet ***[here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17UFRY5IHNNA08M3C6J7KLl_mtZxYNtiZNJ3aPXhfEaM/pubhtml)*** for your reference.

***[Here is the direct link to the JSON data](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/17UFRY5IHNNA08M3C6J7KLl_mtZxYNtiZNJ3aPXhfEaM/od6/public/basic?hl=en_US&alt=json)***, for those who cannot access the link see below for the posted JSON data.

This is my current jQuery JSON code : (Note: the url I am using is valid, but I have not included it below because of its length)

```
$.getJSON('<json-data-url>', function(data) {
    var string = "<table>";       
    for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++) {

      var itemNum = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$itemnum.$t;
      var cost = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$cost.$t;
      var msrp = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$msrp.$t;
      string += '<tr><td>' + itemNum + '</td><td>' + cost + '</td><td>' + msrp + '</td></tr>';

    }

    string += "</table>";

    $(string).appendTo('body');
});
```

The current error that this returns is : *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$t' of underfined*

***[Here is a Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adjit/dSne8/)*** for your testing

I believe this error stems mostly from my inability to accurately read the raw JSON file, so my selector is wrong.

### Raw JSON

```
{"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","feed":{"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom","xmlns$openSearch":"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/","xmlns$gsx":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended","id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/17UFRY5IHNNA08M3C6J7KLl_mtZxYNtiZNJ3aPXhfEaM/od6/public/basic"},"updated":{"$t":"2014-06-18T17:26:03.848Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Sheet1"},"link":[{"rel":"alternate","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17UFRY5IHNNA08M3C6J7KLl_mtZxYNtiZNJ3aPXhfEaM/pubhtml?hl\u003den_US"},{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/17UFRY5IHNNA08M3C6J7KLl_mtZxYNtiZNJ3aPXhfEaM/od6/public/basic"},{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/17UFRY5IHNNA08M3C6J7KLl_mtZxYNtiZNJ3aPXhfEaM/od6/public/basic"},{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/17UFRY5IHNNA08M3C6J7KLl_mtZxYNtiZNJ3aPXhfEaM/od6/public/basic?alt\u003djson"}],"author":[{"name":{"$t":"MetSales1"},"email":{"$t":"metsales1@gmail.com"}}],"openSearch$totalResults":{"$t":"4"},"openSearch$startIndex":{"$t":"1"},"entry":[{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/17UFRY5IHNNA08M3C6J7KLl_mtZxYNtiZNJ3aPXhfEaM/od6/public/basic/cokwr"},"updated":{"$t":"2014-06-18T17:26:03.848Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Linea Pro"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"cost: $590, msrp: $690"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/17UFRY5IHNNA08M3C6J7KLl_mtZxYNtiZNJ3aPXhfEaM/od6/public/basic/cokwr"}]},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/17UFRY5IHNNA08M3C6J7KLl_mtZxYNtiZNJ3aPXhfEaM/od6/public/basic/cpzh4"},"updated":{"$t":"2014-06-18T17:26:03.848Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Infinea Tab"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"cost: $690, msrp: $790"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/17UFRY5IHNNA08M3C6J7KLl_mtZxYNtiZNJ3aPXhfEaM/od6/public/basic/cpzh4"}]},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/17UFRY5IHNNA08M3C6J7KLl_mtZxYNtiZNJ3aPXhfEaM/od6/public/basic/cre1l"},"updated":{"$t":"2014-06-18T17:26:03.848Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Touch Screen"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"cost: $108, msrp: $208"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/17UFRY5IHNNA08M3C6J7KLl_mtZxYNtiZNJ3aPXhfEaM/od6/public/basic/cre1l"}]},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/17UFRY5IHNNA08M3C6J7KLl_mtZxYNtiZNJ3aPXhfEaM/od6/public/basic/chk2m"},"updated":{"$t":"2014-06-18T17:26:03.848Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"AIO Terminal"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"cost: $790, msrp: $890"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/17UFRY5IHNNA08M3C6J7KLl_mtZxYNtiZNJ3aPXhfEaM/od6/public/basic/chk2m"}]}]}}
```

As always... any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm looking in the JSON feed, and there is no `data.feed.entry[i].gsx$itemnum`. What is `gsx$itemnum`? This is nowhere in the JSON, and this is why you are getting undefined errors.

Comment: Same applies for `gsx$cost` and `gsx$msrp`

Comment: @tomaroo first time I'm attempting to use JSON. I have also tried `content$itemnum.$t` that hasn't worked.

Comment: @tomaroo Can you help me out with the selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this site to help you map out your JSON data and see what you have to work with:

http://json.parser.online.fr/

From what I can tell, this may be what you're aiming for:

```
  var id = data.feed.entry[i].id.$t;
  var title = data.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
  var content = data.feed.entry[i].content.$t;
```

There doesn't seem to be a property for cost or msrp in the JSON data.

Edit: I see that the content property stores the cost and msrp info in a string. You can't really do much with it unless you split up/parse the string:

```
  var x = content.split(', '); // ["cost: $590", "msrp: $690"]
  var cost = x[0]; // "cost: $590"
  var msrp = x[1]; // "msrp: $690"

  var $cost = cost.split(' ')[1]; // "$590"
  var $msrp = msrp.split(' ')[1]; // "$690"
```

Comment: Ahh, very cool tool. Is there a way to go deeper into the `$t` from content? like `$t.cost` or are the contents of `$t` just a string? so I would have to parse the string on my own?

Comment: Awesome, that helps a lot. I guess google docs does not use JSON to populate their tables, because it doesn't have cell(1,1). It has columns `cost` and `msrp` in JSON, but not the column `Item Num`

Answer (score 1):

```
function displayContent(json) {
var string = "<table>";      
var len = json.feed.entry.length;
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) 
{
    var itemNum = json.feed.entry[i].gsx$itemnum.$t;
    var cost = json.feed.entry[i].gsx$cost.$t;
    var msrp = json.feed.entry[i].gsx$msrp.$t;
string += '<tr><td>'+itemNum+'</td><td>'+cost+'</td><td>'+msrp+'</td></tr>';
}
string += "</table>";
$(string).appendTo('body');
}
```

After this put callback script
        src="http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/17UFRY5IHNNA08M3C6J7KLl_mtZxYNtiZNJ3aPXhfEaM/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=displayContent" type="text/javascript"

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adhikari18/J98LD/